# MPAndroidChart LineChart without text next to every value

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the Linechart from MPAndroidChart.

```
 List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
 
 ..... /* filling the values */

 LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "my chart"); 
 dataSet.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Here you can see the result

[image]

How can I get rid of the text (11.109, 11.008 ... ) next to every single entry?. I just want to see every single point without the value.

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the values, you can use

```
dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
```

to turn them all off. Have a look at the [dataset base class documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/dataset/) for some more details and other options, and the specific [LineDataSet](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/chart-specific-datasets/) commands.